# Incorrect building of chart (MS Visual Studio Reports 2008)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, sqlreportingservice

I have an SSRS 2008 R2 report.
I use data bellow to build a chart:
[image]

[image]

Incorrect building of chart:
[image]

I want to get that chart:

[image]

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in horizontal axis properties>> axis options tab change interval to 1

[image]